# Is there any server provides image URL for testing?

Tags: images, services, url

I need a large amount of images by URL. For example:

```
http://some-domain/image1.jpg
http://some-domain/image2.jpg
http://some-domain/image3.jpg
http://some-domain/image4.jpg
http://some-domain/image5.jpg
http://some-domain/image6.jpg
....
http://some-domain/image_n.jpg
```

I need it for testing my image library. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where can I ask this kind of question? @.@ This site is about general computing, isn't it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

http://placehold.it/ may be the one you are looking for:

```
http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1
http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2
http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3
http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4
```

and you even can tell sizes and labels.

Comment: I've found others, if you wish: https://placekitten.com/ http://dummyimage.com/  http://lorempixel.com/

Comment: Most of them don't work at the moment. I'm using https://svp.icu/placeholder/

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://postimage.org. When you upload a file it's original name is persevered, as shown beside the "Direct Link". So you'd have http://s9.postimage.org/n92phj9tr/image1.jpg but the part before image1.jpg you can't control. Is this what you want?

Comment: I mean I upload an image like "image1.jpg". There is a button to generate a thousand of images "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", ... , "imagen.jpg" using the same resource. Or maybe some services provide different images with the pattern "1", "2", ... "n" at the end of file extension.